# Церковь - творительный падеж.

Tags: словоформы

При изменении по падежам слова *церковь* **о**  "убегает". Происходит ли то же самое в творительном падеже? Как правильно: *церквью* или *церковью*?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всех падежах кроме единственного числа именительного и творительного, выпадение гласной происходит. Правильно - "церковью"

Им. це́рковь    це́ркви
Р.  це́ркви церкве́й
Д.  це́ркви церквя́м
церква́м
В.  це́рковь    це́ркви
Тв. це́рковью   церквя́ми
церква́ми
Пр. це́ркви церквя́х
церква́х

Answer (score 2):

Я, кажется, понял вопрос.

~1. В творительном падеже нормативно "церковью" и "церквями".

~2. В дательном множестванного по историческим причинам в зачении "храм", "организация" равнонормативны *церквам и церквям*. При этом в значении "афтокефалия" (РПЦ, Болгарская Провославная Церковь и проч) - только *Церквям* (обычно с заглавной).

//-------------
Откуда это?

> Д. ...церква́м
> Тв. ...церква́ми
> Пр. ...церква́х

Насколько понимаю, это от формы цЕрква, некогда альтернативной, ныне уже совершенно не используемой в нормативном языке. Кстати, выпадение гласной, совсем для подобных слов нехарактерное, - оттуда же. Но если уж приводить так полностью:
ЦЕрквА, ЦерквЫ... цЕрквы, цЕркв... и т.д., а не три падежа множественного.

Comment: >это от формы цЕрква, некогда альтернативной, ныне уже совершенно не используемой в нормативном языке.

Если это кому-то интересно, то слово "**церква**" и теперь есть в таких славянских странах, как Хорватия, Сербия и Украина. 

С поправкой на особенности местного произношения. В Сербии и Хорватии перед "р" гласный звук обычно не пишется (там где он был в аналогичном старославянском слове). Например, по-русски  "сербская правосланая церковь", а там -- "српска православна **црква**". А *произносится* это с каким-то очень коротким гласным перед "р", похожим на "ы" или "э".

Comment: Особенно забавно получается в бывшей Югославии со словами, где в старославянском был только один-единственный гласный перед "р". Там гласных не остаётся вообще! :-)
Например, перст (палец) - прст, кровь - крв.

Comment: >церква  
  
А c чего бы ему не быть? "ковь" и "ква" - это два продуктивных рефлекса древнеславянского "-кы", исчезнувшего с появлением ряда новых на тот момент фонетических законов, в частности - исключившего Ы после заднеязычных. 

Сравните: буква - буковь, морковь - морква, брюква - брюковь, в некоторых случаях процесс затронул и другие слова женского рода с конечным Ы: любовь, свекровь и т.д. Поскольку разделение на "-(к)овь" и "-(к)ва" шло достаточно стихийно (точных условий так и не сформулировано), возможны были парные варианты. В разных языках выстояли разные представитель такой пары.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно было узнать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, да. Церковью. По-другому и не выговоришь.